# The data has been accessed and is not available for this column or parameter

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to access the image file in my SQL Server. I am running an Stored procedure and able to get the results in the resultset, but while accessing to the particular image column, it is throwing.

````
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The data has been accessed and is not available for this column or parameter.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:3712) ~[sqljdbc_1.2.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.getValue(dtv.java:247) ~[sqljdbc_1.2.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Column.getValue(Column.java:190) ~[sqljdbc_1.2.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2053) ~[sqljdbc_1.2.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2048) ~[sqljdbc_1.2.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getStream(SQLServerResultSet.java:2067) ~[sqljdbc_1.2.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getBinaryStream(SQLServerResultSet.java:2140) ~[sqljdbc_1.2.jar:?]```
````

Comment: I *hope* by "Image column" you mean a column called `image` and not a column where it's data type is `image`; the `image` data type was deprecated in *2005* (**18 years ago**) and should not be used anymore.

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I'm not sure enough, but this sounds like: You fetched the data once and this is a -you get to call `.getValue` only once- probably because the column's type is BLOB or CLOB (or, gasp, `image` - see @ThomA's excellent comment about how that would be bad), and that means it's streamed once-only and can't be streamed again. If true, the solution is to only call `.getValue()` once per row.

Comment: My image column is a datatype of image only @ThomA

Comment: what datatype should i be used in order to solve this error?

Comment: You should be using `varbinary(MAX)`, @sathishkumar . As I mentioned, `image` was deprecated in *2005*.

Comment: Ok @ThomA I will use this datatype and let u know